# Get html source code through Mailchimp API

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to use the Mailchimp API to download the html code used in a specific campaign.

I was looking at this:
http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/campaigns/campaigns-instance

which works fine, but I do not see how to the get the html source code. Is it because this is not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now , you can access mailchimp v3 api from [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/).
If you want to update html content of a specific campaign. Use this request pattern e.g.

- Unschedule your campaign
- Update campaign HTML Content through PUT Method
- Schedule/Send your campaign

I used python script for mailchimp access in my web application, if you want python script for that ping me...

Answer (score 2):

Campaign creation and editing is [still not available](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/3-roadmap) in v3 of MailChimp's API. You probably won't be able to get the HTML content from version 3 until campaign creation is available.