# Mailchimp API get embedded form code

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have searched [the mailchimp API](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/) for `embedded` and there are no results. I have also googled and stackoverflowed, the closest I can get is [this question related to the templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052871/get-html-source-code-through-mailchimp-api).

The only thing that comes close is [the signup forms](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/signup-forms/#read-get_lists_list_id_signup_forms) which gives me a URL to redirect users to.

Has anyone had any luck with obtaining the `Copy/paste onto your site` section of the embedded forms via the mailchimp API?

[image: Copy paste onto your site]
(Obtained from https://us6.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/integration/embeddedcode?id=XXXXXX)

Comment: Yes I know this is a specific question about the mailchimp API, but mailchimp is a very common mailing list service

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do? There is no copy/paste` form from the MC API.

Comment: @SeanRawles that's not from the API, that screenshot is from the administration area on mailchimp (under embedded forms, as stated in the link)

Comment: Yes sort of, but what are you looking for, exactly? You want the `FORM CODE` or perhaps the `LIST ID` or your `USER ID`?

Comment: And, it specifically sates in the article you reference that the MC API still does not include Roadmap.

Comment: @scoopzilla I want the "Copy/paste onto your site" part, so I guess `FORM CODE`. There is nothing in the API that will give me this, or if it's there it's hidden away under some heavy rocks

Comment: The sign up form is endemic to each list, and is found under the Signup Forms from each list. If you need your API number that is under your account information. The picture that you have there is the `Embedded Form` from a specific list.

Comment: Or are you looking for this [Mailchimp Embed](http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css)

Comment: @scoopzilla "is found under the Signup Forms from each list" and where is it on the API? http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/signup-forms/#read-get_lists_list_id_signup_forms I'm not seeing what ever you're seeing. I want to grab said `Embedded Form` via the API (as per question title)

Comment: @Isaac I am currently looking for the same thing. I don't know if you ended up with a solution, but from the current API, it seems like you can get the signup form info, but not the embedded code using `GET /lists/{list_id}/signup-forms`, with this, you DO get the URL to the hosted form... You could either scrape the html from that URL or embed it in an iframe. It's a bit hacky, but thought it might help.